# Encoding videos locally or through a third party?

Tags: node.js, encoding, ffmpeg, aws-sdk

We're in the process on building a view uploading and sharing community right now and we're currently developing with idea of using a third-party like Zencoder, but what makes Zencoder a better option?

I'm sorry if i butcher up what is involved with supporting a local encoding system, so I'll try to be vague. We plan on releasing with AWS, so why not setup an instance running ffmpeg? I understand it's a lot more then simply that, but if is it that difficult to find someone who can put together an instance for encoding?

Am I right to assume most third party encoding services seem very unrealistic, price wise, for a web application who specifically focus on encoding large amounts of media? I did notice Amazon offers an encoding features and would definitely feel more comfortable using them, but even that seems seems redundant.

I completely understand the cost behind encoding is very real, but I just can't understand why third-party encoders are so widely accepted.

Answer (score 0):

With an encoding service, you are paying for some extras on top of CPU. First is the time and cost to develop you own solution. And second is expertise in encoding. ffmpeg is great for about 99.9% of cases. So expect about one out of 1000 files to give you some problems. Corrupt input closed source codecs, Non Monotonic timestamps, advances container features not supported by ffmpeg. You will find that handling errors and edge cases is about 80% of the effort. And if you are not an expert in video encoding, you will soon need to hire a person who is.